# Use Canonicalize in an xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am creating read-only xpages that take data from a Lotus database.

Among these fields are some that contain the names of the users who worked on the documents, the fields are multivalue.

On my xpage I have inserted a MultilineEditBox so that all users are correctly extracted, I put as MultipleSeparator: @NewLine() so that they go to head.

However the users are displayed like this:

CN=Donald Duck/O=Duckburg

I would like only Donald Duck to appear.

I found that Canonicalize might work for me, but I can't seem to apply it to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonicalize = the format you already have. What you seek is the Common Name (CN), so

```
@Name("[CN]", <YourfieldValues>)
```

should work. I guess you want to define your value list with aliases, so that the display value is CN but the "real" values are in canonicalized format.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a readonly page, you can use a xp:repeat control to loop over the values in the field and format them as needed. Here's an example that you can use:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeatNames" rows="999" value="#{document.fieldWithNames}" indexVar="index" var="personName" removeRepeat="true">
    <xp:text value="#{personName}" escape="true" disableTheme="true">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:customConverter getAsObject="#{javascript:return value}">
                <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:return @Name("[CN]", value)}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
            </xp:customConverter>
        </xp:this.converter>
    </xp:text>
</xp:repeat>
```